# Jupyter Notebook: command for hide the output of a cell?

Tags: ipython, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

In my notebook, I have a cell returning temp calculation results. It's a bit long, so after it is run, I want to hide it and when needed, to show it.

To do it manually, I can double click the left side of the output, to hide it

[image]

After double click
[image]

But is there any way I can do this by code? For example,

the last line of the cell, use a command like `%%hide output`, and the output would be hidden after finished running.

Additionally, can I get this feature in output HTML?

Comment: The only way to control it from the code in the notebook would be to produce custom HTML output that has a hide/show button.

Comment: @ThomasK, so I can not `automatically` hide the output by output something?

Comment: You might actually be able to 'display' some Javascript that gets executed and does it, but it's a bit hackish. I don't know what the JS invocation for it would be.

Answer (score 80):

Add `;` by the end of the cell to hide the output of that cell.

Comment: I may not be clear. I want to hide, but later it could be display if I open a button or something similar.

Comment: Nope, that only eliminates showing latest output of a cell. Example: print 3 ;

Comment: This does not answer the OP... If there is a `print` statement (e.g.) in the cell, it will still show.

Answer (score 58):

In the newer versions(5.0.0 at the time I'm writing this), pressing <kbd>o</kbd> in the command mode hides the output of the cell in focus. The same happens if you triple click in front of the output.

<kbd>o</kbd> is

- the first letter in the word "output" or
- lower case of [15th letter in the alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O)

Comment: this answered the problem I had thanks. By pressing 'o' only the output is hidden and you can press it again to bring the output back :)

Comment: For me, double clicking in front of the output worked. Then, to show the output again a single click was enough.

Comment: Even if this shortcut is useful, it does not answer the OP... The OP means to hide output with a command (perhaps it is not possible).

Answer (score 26):

You can add `%%capture` to the beginning of the cell.

Jupyter provides a magic cell command called `%%capture` that allows you to capture all of to outputs from that cell.

You can use it like this:

`%%capture test
print('test')`

`test.stdout` => 'test\n'

https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html

Comment: `%%capture` also works without target variable. Just add `%%capture` to the beginning of the cell. .

Answer (score 18):

In newer versions of Jupiter Notebook, select the desired cell, make sure you're in command mode and then on the menubar press  <kbd>Cell</kbd> > <kbd>Current Outputs</kbd>. You have then three options:

- Toggle (press <kbd>O</kbd> in the command mode to apply the same effect)
- Toggle Scrolling (the default output)
- Clear (to clear the output all together)

[Image to Menubar Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PMXN.png)

Additionally, you can apply the same effect to all the cells in your document if you chose All Output instead of Current Output.

Comment: Menu:  Cell / All Output / Clear

Answer (score 4):

Not exactly what you are after, but the effect might be good enough for your purposes:

Look into the %%capture magic (https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/1.x/examples/notebooks/Cell%20Magics.ipynb). It lets you assign that cell output to a variable. By calling that variable later you could see the output.

Answer (score 2):

To prepend a cell from getting rendered in the output, in the notebook, by voilo or voila gridstack, just put in the first line of each cell to hide the output:

```py
%%capture --no-display
```

[reference in ipypthon documentation](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#cell-magics)

Comment: Is the addition of `--no-display` to [Hugo's posted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59718646/8508004) necessary for Voila? You don't need `--no-display` for a notebook unless something has changed recently.

Comment: Well this worked on my setup surpessing cell as output using voila. I was searching for getting only some cells rendered in voila running
```bash
voila  --template=gridstack 
```
This brings up a voila website with a file list that includes the notebooks.

Without %%capture --no-display also unwanted cell got displayed. So may be there is a better trick.  I also can not judge if something has changed reacently. Any idea?

Comment: I just tested, and the addition of ` --no-display` is not necessary for Voila, **`%%capture` alone is enough** to block the output from showing in the Voila rendering. And so I'd suggest your answer hasn't added much new here and perhaps the fact that `%%capture` or the `%%capture --no-display`-variant works for Voila would probably have been better as a comment below [Hugo's posted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59718646/8508004) as your suggestion is pretty much the same. Or at least add to yours that `%%capture` alone is sufficient to your answer & throw Hugo an upvote, if you haven't.

Comment: As in the ipython document --no-display is optional. It is described in the IPython documentation  "Don’t capture IPython’s rich display". So that's what I intended and get it more selective.

But working without it works, but it is less selective. So I your happy I'm fine as well

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this](http://chris-said.io/2016/02/13/how-to-make-polished-jupyter-presentations-with-optional-code-visibility/), I just came up with this for myself a few minutes ago:

```
%%javascript

$('#maintoolbar-container').children('#toggleButton').remove()

var toggle_button = ("<button id='toggleButton' type='button'>Show Code</button>");
$('#maintoolbar-container').append(toggle_button);

var code_shown = false;

function code_toggle()
{

    if (code_shown)
    {
        console.log("code shown")
        $('div.input').hide('500');
        $('#toggleButton').text('Show Code');
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("code not shown")
        $('div.input').show('500');
        $('#toggleButton').text('Hide Code');
    }

    code_shown = !code_shown;
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
    code_shown=false;
    $('div.input').hide();
});

$('#toggleButton').on('click', code_toggle);
```

It does have a glitch: each time you run that cell (which I put at the top), it adds a button. So, that is something that needs to be fixed. Would need to check in the `maintoolbar-container` to see if the button already exists, and then not add it.

**EDIT**

I added the necessary piece of code:

```
$('#maintoolbar-container').children('#toggleButton').remove()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the notebook utils from https://github.com/google/etils:

```py
!pip install etils[ecolab]

from etils import ecolab

with etils.collapse():
  print('This content will be hidden by default')
```

It will capture the stdout/stderr output and display it a some collapsible section.

Internally, this is more or less equivalent to:

```
import contextlib
import html
import io
import IPython.display


@contextlib.contextmanager
def collapse(name: str = ''):
  f = io.StringIO()
  with contextlib.redirect_stderr(f):
    with contextlib.redirect_stdout(f):
      yield
  name = html.escape(name)
  content = f.getvalue()
  content = html.escape(content)
  content = f'<pre><code>{content}</code></pre>'
  content = IPython.display.HTML(
      f'<details><summary>{name}</summary>{content}</details>')
  IPython.display.display(content)
```

[image]

The section is collapsed by default, but I uncollapsed it for the screenshot.

Comment: this is a nice hack, any of the other methods did not work in my case as the output was logged from lower-level libraries.

Comment: this is great! in contrast to jupyter_contrib_nbextensions, it also works as html file. is this somehow possible to extend to graphs as well?

Answer (score 1):

Double click on left part of output of jupyter notebook cell.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Y8oB.png)

Answer (score 0):

For Windows,
in Jupyter Notebook, click the cell whose output you want to hide.
Click `Esc + o` for toggling the output

Answer (score 0):

So I totally understand. When you have like 100 different plot and when you do the "Restart & Run All" those ugly plots all show up again 

what you can do is  `ctrl+A` and press `o` it will all of a sudden hide all your cells!!! For you to collapse automatically, you may need to use JupyterLab (another level after JupyterNotebook) but still, by doing `ctrl+A` then `o` you will be able to collapse all the results!!!

`ctrl+A` --> select ALL *(make sure to click outside of coding box before you do it!)* 
`o` --> toggle collapse

Comment: In my computer this shortcut work for Jupyter but not for Jupyterlab

Answer (score 0):

Also you can right click  the cell, and then press  "Clear outputs"

Answer (score -1):

If you don't mind a little hacking, then you may write a simple script for inverting the "collapsed" attribute of each cell from false to true
in the notebook .ipynb file (which is a simple JSON file).
This is however may fail in the future if a the .ipynb format changes.