# Is there a way to toggle cell output in Jupyter Lab?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

In Jupyter Notebook you can toggle the cell output by going into command mode and pressing "O". This command does not work on Jupyter Lab, and I don't see an option to add it. Is there a way to do this, even if it means writing the code for the command?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jupyter Notebook: command for hide the output of a cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37154329/jupyter-notebook-command-for-hide-the-output-of-a-cell)

Comment: @Arkady.A Looks like it to me.

Comment: JupyterLab is different than the classic notebook interface covered at the possible duplicate.

Comment: @Wayne True but the solution of adding ; at the end of an output you want to suppress also works in lab

Answer (score 1):

In Jupyter Notebook you could easily just double click on the cell output to hide it.

This doesn't appear to work in Labs.

Labs has functionality to set keyboard shortcuts.

Settings>Adv Settings> Keyboard Shortcuts
You can then add your own shortcut.
This example uses "H".

```js
{    "shortcuts": [

//First you can optionally make room for your new hotkey if it is taken. 
// {
// "command": "imageviewer:flip-horizontal",
// "keys": [
// "H"
// ],
// "selector": ".jp-ImageViewer",
// "disabled": true
// },




// Then assign a new hotkey
{
"command": "notebook:hide-cell-outputs",
"keys": [
"H"
],
"selector": ".jp-Notebook:focus",
"disabled": false
}

]
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! Works well for me (version 3.1.14). Some notes: to open this file "settings" -> "advanced settings" -> "Keyboard Shortcuts". I noticed that single letter shortcuts key **must** be in uppercase in this config file (if not they are ignored), but their usage is **lowercase** only. Weired

Answer (score 0):

As Arkady said, this looks like a duplicate from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37154329/jupyter-notebook-command-for-hide-the-output-of-a-cell). Note, you can also do this in the sidebar if you don't want to code it.

[image]

Comment: I'd also add that these abilities are presently available under the `View` menu in JupyterLab. There is `Collapse` and `Expand` sections for selected code, selected output, all code, or all outputs.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the blue vertical bar to the left of the output or code cell to hide/toggle them. Found this when I accidentally clicked on it :)