# How can I silence logs of a command in .ipynb file?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, warnings, kaggle

How can I hide the results of a terminal command?

I'm ran this code on google-colab:

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install -U pandas-profiling[notebook]
!jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension
```

I already tried using `warning` library, but it didn't work.

And I'm getting these logs in the file that I'd like to hide:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pandas-profiling[notebook] in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (3.1.0)
Collecting pandas-profiling[notebook]
  Downloading pandas_profiling-3.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (262 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 262.6/262.6 KB 1.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=1.4.1 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pandas-profiling[notebook]) (1.7.3)
Requirement already satisfied: PyYAML>=5.0.0 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pandas-profiling[notebook]) (6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pydantic>=1.8.1 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pandas-profiling[notebook]) (1.8.2)
Collecting markupsafe~=2.1.1
  Downloading MarkupSafe-2.1.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (25 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.16.0 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pandas-profiling[notebook]) (1.21.5)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm>=4.48.2 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pandas-profiling[notebook]) (4.63.0)
Requirement already satisfied: seaborn>=0.10.1 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pandas-profiling[notebook]) (0.11.2)
Collecting joblib~=1.1.0
  Downloading joblib-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (306 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 307.0/307.0 KB 4.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Requirement already satisfied: phik>=0.11.1 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pandas-profiling[notebook]) (0.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib>=3.2.0 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pandas-profiling[notebook]) (3.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: missingno>=0.4.2 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pandas-profiling[notebook]) (0.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.24.0 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pandas-profiling[notebook]) (2.27.1)
Requirement already satisfied: multimethod>=1.4 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pandas-profiling[notebook]) (1.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas!=1.0.0,!=1.0.1,!=1.0.2,!=1.1.0,>=0.25.3 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pandas-profiling[notebook]) (1.3.5)
Requirement already satisfied: visions[type_image_path]==0.7.4 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pandas-profiling[notebook]) (0.7.4)
Requirement already satisfied: jinja2>=2.11.1 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pandas-profiling[notebook]) (3.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: htmlmin>=0.1.12 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pandas-profiling[notebook]) (0.1.12)
Collecting tangled-up-in-unicode==0.2.0
  Downloading tangled_up_in_unicode-0.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (4.7 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 4.7/4.7 MB 21.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-core>=4.6.3 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pandas-profiling[notebook]) (4.9.2)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-client>=5.3.4 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pandas-profiling[notebook]) (7.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: ipywidgets>=7.5.1 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pandas-profiling[notebook]) (7.6.5)
Requirement already satisfied: networkx>=2.4 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from visions[type_image_path]==0.7.4->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (2.5)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=19.3.0 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from visions[type_image_path]==0.7.4->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (21.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: imagehash in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from visions[type_image_path]==0.7.4->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (4.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from visions[type_image_path]==0.7.4->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (9.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: traitlets>=4.3.1 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (5.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyterlab-widgets>=1.0.0 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (1.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: ipykernel>=4.5.1 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (6.9.2)
Requirement already satisfied: nbformat>=4.2.0 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (5.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: widgetsnbextension~=3.5.0 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (3.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied: ipython-genutils~=0.2.0 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: ipython>=4.0.0 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (7.32.0)
Requirement already satisfied: entrypoints in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from jupyter-client>=5.3.4->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from jupyter-client>=5.3.4->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pyzmq>=13 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from jupyter-client>=5.3.4->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (22.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tornado>=4.1 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from jupyter-client>=5.3.4->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: nest-asyncio>=1.5 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from jupyter-client>=5.3.4->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (1.5.4)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=20.0 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from matplotlib>=3.2.0->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (21.3)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from matplotlib>=3.2.0->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (1.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: fonttools>=4.22.0 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from matplotlib>=3.2.0->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (4.30.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.2.1 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from matplotlib>=3.2.0->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (3.0.7)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from matplotlib>=3.2.0->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (0.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.3 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pandas!=1.0.0,!=1.0.1,!=1.0.2,!=1.1.0,>=0.25.3->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (2021.3)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions>=3.7.4.3 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pydantic>=1.8.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (4.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests>=2.24.0->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (1.26.8)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer~=2.0.0 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests>=2.24.0->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (2.0.12)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests>=2.24.0->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests>=2.24.0->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (2021.10.8)
Requirement already satisfied: debugpy<2.0,>=1.0.0 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from ipykernel>=4.5.1->ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (1.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: psutil in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from ipykernel>=4.5.1->ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (5.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib-inline<0.2.0,>=0.1.0 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from ipykernel>=4.5.1->ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (0.1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: jedi>=0.16 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (0.18.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pygments in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (2.11.2)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=18.5 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (59.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pexpect>4.3 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (4.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pickleshare in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (0.7.5)
Requirement already satisfied: prompt-toolkit!=3.0.0,!=3.0.1,<3.1.0,>=2.0.0 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (3.0.27)
Requirement already satisfied: decorator in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (5.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: backcall in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: jsonschema!=2.5.0,>=2.4 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from nbformat>=4.2.0->ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (4.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.1->jupyter-client>=5.3.4->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: notebook>=4.4.1 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from widgetsnbextension~=3.5.0->ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (6.4.10)
Requirement already satisfied: PyWavelets in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from imagehash->visions[type_image_path]==0.7.4->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (1.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: parso<0.9.0,>=0.8.0 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from jedi>=0.16->ipython>=4.0.0->ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (0.8.3)
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-metadata in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from jsonschema!=2.5.0,>=2.4->nbformat>=4.2.0->ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (4.11.3)
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-resources>=1.4.0 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from jsonschema!=2.5.0,>=2.4->nbformat>=4.2.0->ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (5.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyrsistent!=0.17.0,!=0.17.1,!=0.17.2,>=0.14.0 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from jsonschema!=2.5.0,>=2.4->nbformat>=4.2.0->ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (0.18.1)
Requirement already satisfied: argon2-cffi in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.5.0->ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (21.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: terminado>=0.8.3 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.5.0->ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (0.13.3)
Requirement already satisfied: nbconvert>=5 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.5.0->ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (6.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: prometheus-client in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.5.0->ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (0.13.1)
Requirement already satisfied: Send2Trash>=1.8.0 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.5.0->ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (1.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: ptyprocess>=0.5 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pexpect>4.3->ipython>=4.0.0->ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (0.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: wcwidth in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from prompt-toolkit!=3.0.0,!=3.0.1,<3.1.0,>=2.0.0->ipython>=4.0.0->ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (0.2.5)
Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=3.1.0 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from importlib-resources>=1.4.0->jsonschema!=2.5.0,>=2.4->nbformat>=4.2.0->ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (3.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: mistune<2,>=0.8.1 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from nbconvert>=5->notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.5.0->ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (0.8.4)
Requirement already satisfied: defusedxml in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from nbconvert>=5->notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.5.0->ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (0.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pandocfilters>=1.4.1 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from nbconvert>=5->notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.5.0->ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (1.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tinycss2 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from nbconvert>=5->notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.5.0->ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (1.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from nbconvert>=5->notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.5.0->ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (4.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: nbclient>=0.5.0 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from nbconvert>=5->notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.5.0->ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (0.5.13)
Requirement already satisfied: bleach in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from nbconvert>=5->notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.5.0->ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (4.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyterlab-pygments in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from nbconvert>=5->notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.5.0->ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (0.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: argon2-cffi-bindings in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from argon2-cffi->notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.5.0->ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (21.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.0.1 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from argon2-cffi-bindings->argon2-cffi->notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.5.0->ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: soupsieve>1.2 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from beautifulsoup4->nbconvert>=5->notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.5.0->ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (2.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: webencodings in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from bleach->nbconvert>=5->notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.5.0->ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (0.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from cffi>=1.0.1->argon2-cffi-bindings->argon2-cffi->notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.5.0->ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (2.21)
Installing collected packages: tangled-up-in-unicode, markupsafe, joblib, pandas-profiling
  Attempting uninstall: tangled-up-in-unicode
    Found existing installation: tangled-up-in-unicode 0.1.0
    Uninstalling tangled-up-in-unicode-0.1.0:
      Successfully uninstalled tangled-up-in-unicode-0.1.0
  Attempting uninstall: markupsafe
    Found existing installation: MarkupSafe 2.0.1
    Uninstalling MarkupSafe-2.0.1:
      Successfully uninstalled MarkupSafe-2.0.1
  Attempting uninstall: joblib
    Found existing installation: joblib 1.0.1
    Uninstalling joblib-1.0.1:
      Successfully uninstalled joblib-1.0.1
  Attempting uninstall: pandas-profiling
    Found existing installation: pandas-profiling 3.1.0
    Uninstalling pandas-profiling-3.1.0:
      Successfully uninstalled pandas-profiling-3.1.0
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
beatrix-jupyterlab 3.1.7 requires google-cloud-bigquery-storage, which is not installed.
pdpbox 0.2.1 requires matplotlib==3.1.1, but you have matplotlib 3.5.1 which is incompatible.
Successfully installed joblib-1.1.0 markupsafe-2.1.1 pandas-profiling-3.2.0 tangled-up-in-unicode-0.2.0
WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
Enabling notebook extension jupyter-js-widgets/extension...
      - Validating: OK
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the first sentence [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60306327/8508004) you can use IPython's/Jupyter cell magic to 'capture' the noisy output of a cell. And then just not do anything with it. The cell would resemble this for your example code:

```
%%capture
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install -U pandas-profiling[notebook]
!jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension
```

The use of the cell magic `%%capture` at the starting line of a cell is handy trick for suppressing all (I believe) output in a cell, in addition to using it to actually capture cell output for recall/use later.