# How to suppress a pip install error in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, pip

I am trying to install a pip package, without getting any output of that cell, but I can't suppress this error:

```
!pip install -qqq llama-cpp-python --force-reinstall --upgrade --no-cache-dir --progress-bar off
```

> ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account
> all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of
> the following dependency conflicts.
> cudf 23.8.0 requires cupy-cuda11x>=12.0.0, which is not installed.
> cuml 23.8.0 requires cupy-cuda11x>=12.0.0, which is not installed.
> dask-cudf 23.8.0 requires cupy-cuda11x>=12.0.0, which is not
> installed. apache-beam 2.46.0 requires dill<0.3.2,>=0.3.1.1, but you
> have dill 0.3.7 which is incompatible.

and the list goes on...

1. How could I suppress this error message?
2. How could I resolve it?

Comment: See how the error message tells you that some packages are required and not installed? did you try installing them separately? What happens if you try doing that?

Comment: Here you don't want to suppress the output because you need to address it to get it to install. This won't solve your environment issue, but for a better experience going forward in your Jupyter use: If you are using true, modern Jupyter then you should not be using an exclamation point with the install command for running inside a modern Jupyter notebook. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more about the magic install commands added a few years ago to insure the installation occurs in ...

Comment: <continuned> the proper environment where the kernel is running that underlies the active .ipynb file. Don't follow any advice that says to use an exclamation point with install commands inside a notebook. That is outdated and can lead to issues and in fact was part of why the magic commands were added to make it more user-friendly and universal. See [the second paragraph here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez) to get a better sense about how the exclamation point use with installs can lead to issues and confusion.

Comment: In your case, it would be a bad idea to 'suppress' displaying the error because you need to deal with the issue, but [see my answer to 'How can I silence logs of a command in .ipynb file?'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72765876/8508004) for how you may do that. For completeness sake about 'suppressing output' in cells, sometimes there's C-level output in cells and you can add in wurlitzer use to suppress that, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76517637/8508004). **As for resolving the issue you have**, look into making an environment with compatible software versions in it, such as dill.

Comment: I get it, those errors should better be fixed, switching to jupyter magic `%pip install -qqq llama-cpp-python --progress-bar off` now seems to solve the issues completely. Thanks!