# How do you suppress output in JupyterLab, generated through libraries (EconML)?

Tags: output, jupyter, jupyter-lab

**How do you hide output in a Jupyter Notebook VM (specifically pink boxes that aren't warnings)?**

I am running code using the EconML library, specifically the CausalAnalysis() method, and one output is hundreds of lines of `lbfgs failed to converge (status=1):`. I'm not trying to fix this issue as it's due to the method, and fixed later on in my script. I'm just trying to block the output!

I've tried

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
```

but as it's not a warning, nothing is being suppressed.

I've also tried `%%capture` and other advice from [Jupyter Notebook: command for hide the output of a cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37154329/jupyter-notebook-command-for-hide-the-output-of-a-cell) but no luck.